# Неверное определение кодировки mb_detect_encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, кодировка, codepage

Необходимо выбрать содержимое тега title. Обрабатываю с помощью DOM парсера. Когда сохраняю у себя и открываю в редакторе содержимое тега title отображается нормально - кириллица.  На php-странице и при сохранении в БД выглядит так - ÐÐ°ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¾Ð³ ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³ Ð¾Ð½Ð»Ð°Ð¹Ð½ â ÑÐ¸ÑÐ°Ð¹ÑÐµ Ð¾Ð½Ð»Ð°Ð¹Ð½ Ð¸ ÑÐºÐ°ÑÐ¸Ð²Ð°Ð¹ÑÐµ Ð±ÐµÑÐ¿Ð»Ð°ÑÐ½Ð¾ ÑÐµÐ´ÐµÐ²ÑÑ ÑÑÑÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ ÐºÐ»Ð°ÑÑÐ¸ÑÐµÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ Ð»Ð¸ÑÐµÑÐ°ÑÑÑÑ.

Получаю содержимое страницы. Определяю кодировку функцией mb_detect_encoding - выводит "UTF-8". Однако декодер студии Лебедева (https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/) определяет ее как ISO-8859-1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перекодирую из ISO-8859-1 в UTF-8 - получаю еще один вид "крокозябов" - ÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂ»ÃÂ¾ÃÂ³ ÃÂºÃÂ½ÃÂ¸ÃÂ³ ÃÂ¾ÃÂ½ÃÂ»ÃÂ°ÃÂ¹ÃÂ½ Ã¢ÂÂ ÃÂÃÂ¸ÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂ¹ÃÂÃÂµ ÃÂ¾ÃÂ½ÃÂ»ÃÂ°ÃÂ¹ÃÂ½ ÃÂ¸ ÃÂÃÂºÃÂ°ÃÂÃÂ¸ÃÂ²ÃÂ°ÃÂ¹ÃÂÃÂµ ÃÂ±ÃÂµÃÂÃÂ¿ÃÂ»ÃÂ°ÃÂÃÂ½ÃÂ¾ ÃÂÃÂµÃÂ´ÃÂµÃÂ²ÃÂÃÂ ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂºÃÂ¾ÃÂ¹ ÃÂºÃÂ»ÃÂ°ÃÂÃÂÃÂ¸ÃÂÃÂµÃÂÃÂºÃÂ¾ÃÂ¹ ÃÂ»ÃÂ¸ÃÂÃÂµÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ.

Вот код обработки:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('https://www.culture.ru/literature'));

$tlt = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");

foreach ($tlt as $element)
{
    $title = $element->nodeValue;

    // Исходный текст
    echo "Исходный текст: ".$title.'<br>';
    // Определение кодировки - UTF-8
    echo "Кодировка: ".mb_detect_encoding($title).'<br>';
    // Перекодируем в utf-8
    echo "Название: ".iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $title).'<br>';

}
```

Вопроса 2:

1. Почему функция PHP возвращает одну кодировку, а скрипт Лебедева - другую (причем нормально форматирует в кириллицу)?
2. Как мне в данном случае преобразовать этот текст к кириллице?

Answer (score 1):

В этой функции нет какой-то магии, которая позволит для заданного куска бинарника угадать кодировку текста. Ключевое слово "угадать". Что такое кодировка? Таблица соответствия байт и отображаемых символов. Если у вас есть только бинарная строка байт - этого недостаточно чтобы узнать как это отображать. Для большинства кодировок мира определено значение для любого возможного байта (собственно потому столь много кодировок некогда и появилось, что многобайтовые кодировки было дорого, а однобайтовые - мало). Если для всех байтов есть значения - то и отобразить можем в любой из этих кодировок. Можно только попробовать угадать что из этого пользователь сочтёт имеющим смысл.

---

> Необходимо выбрать содержимое тега title

Ищите кодировку в HTTP-ответе сервера и в meta-тегах. Хотя особое счастье если они различаются... Сейчас с этим заметно проще чем 15-20 лет назад, можно рассчитывать что в HTTP заголовках кодировка указана и указана корректно.

Comment: А с данным примером - как привести кодировку к читаемому виду?

Comment: То есть верно ее определить. Как ISO.

Comment: Единственный способ точно знать кодировку текста - договориться об этом. И в html и в HTTP есть для этого отметки. Необязательные, к сожалению, в отличии от, например, XML (где всё отличное от UTF8 должно быть явно указано и не обязательно к реализации вовсе) или JSON (где допустим только юникод).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Название:" . mb_convert_encoding($title, 'ISO-8859-1', 'auto') . "</br>";
// или
echo "Название: " . utf8_decode($title) . "</br>";
```

[mb_convert_encoding — Преобразует кодировку символов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

[What is the difference between iconv() and mb_convert_encoding() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233517/what-is-the-difference-between-iconv-and-mb-convert-encoding-in-php)

Comment: Спасибо,   это работает, попробую разобраться как. А как же мне программно определить что это ISO?

Comment: Так а вы и не опеделяли. ISO-8859-1 - это та кодировка которую вы хотите сейчас использовать. Т.е. это вы задаёте, в какую кодировку переводить текст.